Dns not working after accidentally deleting etc/resolv.conf
I accidentally deleted respv.conf and after reboot it generated an empty linked file in its place but I am unable to ping or access the internet

What command exactly did you run to delete the file, and to try to recreate it ? Also, what is the output of ls -l /etc/resolv.conf and the content of same file ?

I used rn -rf and output of the command islrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 23 dec 29 12:45 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../var/run/resolv.conf and the file is empty

20.04 would use systemd iirc - does /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf exist and contain sensible values?

Yes it has the old values

Then you can create a softlink to this File.

Pinging 8.8.8.8 works but not google.com idk why this is happening

How to create a softlink @nobody

sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
